# Product page gives 404 - even though the product exists?

Tags: magento-1.9, product

**Magento 1.9.3.7**

My product has the id 541 and the URL is https://example.com/catalog/product/view/id/541/s/presse-marburg/. Now when I open the URL, it always gives me a 404.

The product is activated, visible and I cleared the cache and reindexed several times. The product can not be found by searching, even though its visible in catalog and search.

Any ideas what might be causing this?

Thanks!

Comment: Make sure website field assigned to the products.

Comment: Oh my ... that did the trick! Thanks so much!

Comment: Great,, help to others by accepting my answer and upvoting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check all the fields enabled, Make sure website field assigned to the products